# How to correctly get data from an API in this for loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to fill the div "video-choices" with images from the API, each one image should fill an `img` inside the `div` "video-choices".

```html
<div class="videos-container">

  <div class="video-player">
    your videos will play here
  </div>

  <div class="video-choices">
  </div>

</div>
```

I have done this

```js
const api= "https://scotch-mvplayer-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1"

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'https://scotch-mvplayer-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1', true);

request.onload = function () {
       var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
     var videos = document.querySelector('.video-choices');
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
          videos.innerHTML = data[i].name;
        }

}

request.send();
```

But then I get stuck in that. Because if before I do several `img` inside the `div` then in the for loop I can´t change the `innerHTML` of all the `img` at the same time, but if I do like it's now written, of course it gets overwritten and only one image only loads.

I think I might need the use of the `createElement` thing of the DOM, but I have tried and it seems I can´t grasp it correctly because my code never makes enough sense to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a version using `createElement` and `appendChild` to achieve what you want. I'm not sure where the image source comes from (probably from `data`) but I've left that for you to replace.

```javascript
request.onload = function () {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
      var videos = document.querySelector('.video-choices');
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
          var videoImg = document.createElement("img");
          videoImg.src = "{URL_HERE}";
          videos.appendChild(videoImg);
      }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that exactly what i was thinking of to solve it,I can´t believe it is this simple. I think I was pretty near of the solution but i gave up because i thought it couldn´t be possible asigning just a variable inside the loop because then it would get overwritten. I think I just don´t understand for loops in programming at 100% yet because the code doesn´t make sense 100% to me yet it works perfectly lol

Answer (score 1):

Your first mistake is misspelling. "lenght" -> "length"

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
```

Your second deficiency is "append".

`videos.innerHTML = data[i].name;` to `videos.innerHTML += data[i].name;`

**Here is the result**

```js
const api= "https://scotch-mvplayer-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1"

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', 'https://scotch-mvplayer-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1', true);

    request.onload = function () {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
 
         var videos = document.querySelector('.video-choices');
         videos.innerHTML = "";
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
              videos.innerHTML += "<li><img style='max-width: 50px' src='"+data[i].poster+"' />"+data[i].name+"</li>";
            }
        
    }

    request.send();
```

```html
<div class="videos-container">
  
  <div class="video-player">
    your videos will play here
  </div>
  
  <ul class="video-choices">
<li> LOADING... </li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I hardly ever use XMLHttpRequest anymore, but when I learned, I learned it like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);

    /**
     * 
     * @param {*} e event
     * @prop {e} assumes request has been sent
     */
    xhr.onprogress = function (e) {
        document.body.className = "loading";
    }

    xhr.onload = function () {
      let status = this.status;
      if ((status >= 200 && status < 300) || status === 304) {
        let res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        // if you need the key of your payload, use Object.keys(res)
        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
            let li = document.createElement('li');
            el.appendChild(li)
    }

    xhr.onerror = function(e) { console.error(e); }
    xhr.send();
```

What's difference about yours and mine is that I'm creating a new element and appending it to the DOM for every index in the res array

Answer (score 0):

```js
const api= "https://scotch-mvplayer-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1"

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', api, true);

request.onload = function () {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
     var videos = document.getElementsByClassName('video-player')[0];
     
        let VideosDiv='';
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            let title="<div class='video-title'>"+data[i]['name']+"</div>";
            let year="<div class='video-year'>"+data[i]['year']+"</div>";
            let ifm="<div><iframe width='420' height='315' src='' frameborder='0' allowTransparency='true' allowfullscreen data-src="+data[i]['trailer']+"></iframe></div>";
            let poster=data[i]['poster'];
            let video=
"<div>"+title+year+ifm+"<div>";
            VideosDiv=VideosDiv+video;
        }
         videos.innerHTML =  VideosDiv;
        
}

request.send();
```

```css
.video{
  display:block;
  margin:16px;
}

.video-title{
   font-size:16px;
   color:#212121;
}

.video-year{
   font-size:16px;
   color:#727272;
}

.video-poster{
   height:100px;
   width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="videos-container">
  
  <div class="video-player">
    your videos will play here
  </div>
  
  <div class="video-choices">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

data doesn't have the property *lenght*, it's **length** :-)

Does fixing that help with your issue?

Comment: Lol Yeah, I was wondering why this time it wasn´t working not even in the "bad way". Now at least it loads one img. But my issue is still present .